# Flask subdomain variable not captured, other routes 404

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use Flask's subdomain parameter, but having some trouble.

I've configured my local /etc/hosts/ file to point example.com and blog.example.com to 127.0.0.1.

For the '`index`' route the subdomain parameter doesn't get captured when I browse to http://blog.example.com:5000.  When I try to print `var` it prints "var is ".

The '`login`' route 404s, but I can't figure out why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'


# prints "var is <invalid>"
@app.route('/', subdomain="<var>", methods=['GET'])
def index(var):
    print "var is %s" % var
    return "Hello World %s" % var

# This 404s
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    return "Login Here!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='example.com', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the port number in your `SERVER_NAME` config.

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com:5000'
```

Should fix it.

Comment: That works, but now it 404s for the index route when I don't use a subdomain.  Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: To clarify:  I'd like a single route to optionally handle requests for subdomains.  So the user would be able to browse http://blog.example.com/post/123 or http://example.com/blog/post/123  Is that possible without duplicating a bunch of code?

Comment: Figured it out!  Just needed to add another route decorator like so: @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])

Comment: Just realized that I didn't actually say thank you.  So, thank you!