# Catching a subdomain in Flask but with custom domain name hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Basically, I am trying to catch subdomains for my website (such as `www.example.com` or `help.example.com`). I followed the instructions of solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021691/dynamic-subdomain-handling-in-a-web-app-flask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561177/flask-subdomain-variable-not-captured-other-routes-404). For some reason, it identifies as:

```
This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in www.example.com.
```

In general, this is what most answers said:

1. Use the `subdomain="<subdomain>"` argument in the decorator declaration in Flask.
2. Declare the server name i.e. `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "example.com:33507"`
   N.B. -> I wrote 33507 as the port Heroku uses.

But even after performing all of these steps, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following Flask example code will respond to a subdomain called "api" and serve up the decorated `api_index` route. Note for this to work I didn't specify the port for the server name config.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "example.com"


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Welcome"


@app.route("/", subdomain="api")
def api_index():
    return jsonify({"message": "Welcome"})
```

In Heroku, you will need to add a custom domain for each subdomain you require. It is possible to use a wildcard but you will have to [provide your own certificate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#providing-your-own-tls-certificate).

I've just tried this successfully on Heroku with the following Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

And the following dependencies using Pipenv

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"
gunicorn = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```

If this doesn't help, you can edit your message to include your code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 2 things. 1) I added the code at the start to my Flask App. The error message changed to ```This page isn’t workingapi.wonderweb.live didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE```. 2) Is it necessary to make changes to my certificate?

Comment: I also changed the Procfile. It still shows the same error

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: I had not added an ANAME dns record for the custom subdomain. NOW IT WORKS!